# Are we allowed to show a user's friend's profile photo in our mobile app to other users?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, permissions, photo, profile, image

The user of our app would create a group using his friend list. His friends don't have to use the app. Is it ok to show the friend's profile photo within our app without their consent to other non-friend users? Since their profile photo is public anyway, does this mean we can display it to our users too? What about other information like Name, Age, or Gender?

Thank you!

Comment: Let's turn it around. Alice is friends with Bob and Carla. Carla has blocked Bob. Alice attempts to create a group between the tree. Is it okay for some random app run by a different user to override that block?

Comment: However, block on Facebook does not block user Bob from viewing the open graph info if he knows Carla's url or ID. Facebook blocks Bob from finding Carla in search or communicating with her. But simply viewing the basic info of Name, Gender, and Photo appear to be fair game regardless of block status.

So long as only this information is provided and nothing else it appears to be ok. Additional functionality between those users, such as chat, would require them to be opt-in users of the app.

Comment: I'm not sure how blocking works the other way, but I do know for sure that if I block someone, that someone is completely invisible to me, I cannot see *anything* from that user, even if I go directly to the profile page.

Answer (score 0):

I think what information you can get from user profile without asking a permission is public. I would though suggest you to put a terms and condition page with what you intent to do with user information. And mandate to user to read and agree to it. You are safe then.